# operator is invalid for atomic vector inside function

Tags: r

I am running a function with the code below inside the function.

Should I be declaring something as a dataframe where I am not?

When it runs I get

> "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

If I redefine `z2$a` as `z2[,1]` in the creation of the `ma2` dataframe I get.

> Error in z2[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

```
 #---identifieds the loaction of the business address header and mailing address header
    ba <- grep("BUSINESS ADDRESS:",z$a)
    ma <- grep("MAIL ADDRESS:", z$a)

#-- create the business address dataframe from the main dataframe "z"
#--- if no "business address" header is found then set z2 dataframe to NA
#--- if yes on "business address" header set the z2 fram to the header  location and all
#--- rows below
  if(length(ba) > 0) {
    z2 <- z[ba:nrow(z),,drop = FALSE]
  } else {
    z2 <- NA
  }

#--- trim the business address df z2 if the mailing address is in the dataframe.
#--- if mailing address header "MAIL ADDRESS:" is found then the if statement
#--- will chop off mailing address and everything below it.
#--- if mailing address header is not found the z2 dataframe will remain as is

  ma2 <- grep("MAIL ADDRESS:",z2$a)

  if(length(ma2) > 0) {
    z2 <- z2[1:((ma2)-1),,drop = FALSE]
  } else {
    z2
  }
```

Comment: Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Part of the question should be a small set of input data (use `dput(your_data_frame)` to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you could try adding `str(z2)` right before the line with `z2$a` to see what `z2` looks like right before the error happens - or, if the output would be voluminous, use `options(error=recover)` to drop into a debugger when the error happens

Comment: probably `z2` is a vector only..

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you both.  I'm back up and rolling.  I added as.data.frame to convert to a dataframe and all is well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z2` was not being created as a data frame.
adding `as.data.frame()` took care of everything.